# Replacing strings with docvariables located within textboxes

Tags: ms-word, textbox, docvariable

I am replacing strings of text with automation with DocVariable fields. The only issues is when these strings, going forward I will referrer to as TAGS, is when the TAG is located within "TextBox" Controls.

I use two modules to replace tags with DOCVARIABLES

***TAG Example:
**"DEPARTMENT_NAME"** *string text*

DOCVARIABLE EXAMPLE:
**{DOCVARIABLE "Department_Name" * MERGEFORMAT}*****

---

**Module 1**

```
Public Function PopulateDocuments() As Boolean

Dim Department_Name As String
Department_Name = "Department_Name"
ReplaceWithDocVar "DEPARTMENT_NAME", "Department_Name"
End Function
```

---

**Module 2**

```
Public Function ReplaceWithDocVar(strFind As String, strVarName As String) As Boolean
Dim oStory As Range
Dim TextColor As Range
Dim strDocName As String
Dim orgDocName As String
Dim orgPath As String
Dim intPos As Integer
Dim docpath As String
Dim docname As String
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        With oStory.Find

            Do While .Execute(FindText:=strFind, MatchCase:=True, MatchWholeWord:=True)
                
                oStory.Text = ""
                'oStory.Text = wdBlue

                oStory.Fields.Add Range:=oStory, _
                                  Type:=wdFieldDocVariable, _
                                  Text:=Chr(34) & strVarName & Chr(34), _
                                  PreserveFormatting:=True

                oStory.Collapse 0

            Loop
        End With
        If oStory.StoryType <> wdMainTextStory Then
            While Not (oStory.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
                Set oStory = oStory.NextStoryRange
                With oStory.Find

                    Do While .Execute(FindText:=strFind, MatchCase:=True, MatchWholeWord:=True)

                        oStory.Text = ""
                        'oStory.Text = wdBlue
                        oStory.Fields.Add Range:=oStory, _
                                          Type:=wdFieldDocVariable, _
                                          Text:=Chr(34) & strVarName & Chr(34), _
                                          PreserveFormatting:=True
                        'oStory.Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
                        oStory.Collapse 0

                    Loop
                End With
            Wend
        End If
    Next oStory
    Set oStory = Nothing
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Note: I am not the author of this code but it runs very well all of the same.

I do not see any error messages when replacing those TAGs that I can locate. All TAGS excluding those in textboxes are correctly replaced with DOCVARIABLES.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Who is the author of the code? What is the source?

Answer (score 0):

TextBoxes are Shapes within the document. You have to search for Shapes in the document and then determine if the Shape is a TextBox with text content. In any event, the search for TextBoxes and then the examination of their text content will have to be separate from your other searches through the document story ranges of your current code.

Here is some sample code for searching TextBoxes. Adapt it as required for your project.

```
Dim shp As Word.Shape
Dim rng As Word.Range
For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
    If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
        If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
            Set rng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
            With rng.Find
                'add your find and replace criteria here
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I receive specified value is out of range error on the "If shp.TextFrame2.HasText Then"
Run-Time Error '-2147467263 (80004001)

Comment: Change from TextFrame2 to just TextFrame and see if that works.

Comment: Text frame stops the error. The issue is what is the for want of a better name full Word equivalent of a URL path to the DocVariable within the textbox.
wrd1 is the document

Comment: Isn't the find value the same as the value of "strFind" that you used in Module 2 of your code? What you are saying about "wrd1 is the document" is not clear to me.